# How do I convert 20190801 to Aug-2019

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I have a column which is an integer 201908. I need to out this as Aug-2019.

I know in SQl, its easy to do: If salesmonth is the name of the column

UPPER(FORMAT(cast(cast(salesmonth as varchar(10)) + '01' as date),'MMM-yyyy'))

How do I do this in Hive?

I converted salesmonth to varchar and added 01 to make it 20190801. I tried date_parse to %MMM-%yy but pretty sure I am not doing it right.

```
select salesmonth, concat(cast(salesmonthas varchar(10)),'01') as t1
,date_format(concat(cast(salesmonth as varchar(10)),'01'),'%MMM-%yyyy') as t2
from ${db['PL_SALES']} where salesmonth= 201908 limit 10
```

Expected Output: AUG-19

Error: Invalid_Function_Argument. Invalid Format: 20190801

EDIT:

This is easier to handle with Case statements - but I am hoping to avoid case and looking for a similar format as SQL.

Comment: Question is tagged slightly ambiguously. Are you querying Hive or Athena, which is based on Presto? (I answered assuming the latter.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`date_parse`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse) to parse `'20190801'` into a date (actually a `timestamp`):

```
presto:default> SELECT date_parse('20190801', '%Y%m%d');
          _col0
-------------------------
 2019-08-01 00:00:00.000
```

You can then use [`date_format`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_format) to render the required result:

```
presto:default> SELECT date_format(date_parse('20190801', '%Y%m%d'), '%b-%Y');
  _col0
----------
 Aug-2019
```

Or, if you want something like `'AUG-19'`:

```
presto:default> SELECT upper(date_format(date_parse('20190801', '%Y%m%d'), '%b-%y'));
 _col0
--------
 AUG-19
```